# How to find seleced item from menuitem

Tags: wpf, click, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a `ContextMenu` in which I bound some items as `MenuItem` at runtime.
I have subscribed a `Click` event also.

Now how to find wwhich item was clicked from the bound item in the event?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is merely speculation, but in WPF, there are two main ways. First one is to check the `SelectedItem` property from your object if it has one.

The other one is to chech the arguments that are passed to the event. If your event have a `RoutedEventArgs`, this variable will contains a property called `Source` which should contains the object that called the event. This could be used for example, when you have a `Button` inside a `ListView` `ItemTemplate` and you want to know which one was clicked.